# MoveFile() is not working

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

This is the line I have written for movefile(). It is not working. Maybe the directory path is too long or something.. Do you have any idea about what could be wrong?

```
MoveFile("C:\\AP\\PCP\\APDATA\\test.txt", "C:\\AP\\PCW\\APSave\\New Folder\\test.txt");
```

Comment: You should post what error code it returns.

Comment: What value does `GetLastError()` return after `MoveFile()` fails?

Comment: Maybe it is the space in 'New Folder' causing the problem?

Comment: I saw the exact same question a couple of hours ago, but it seems to have been deleted.

Comment: Just to be certain, by not working do you mean "fails to move the file" or "fails to compile"?

Comment: @digvijay I'm wondering as well what 'not working' means here. You should update your question with some more information.

Comment: Did your code only have 1 backslash for each directory as you originally posted? You need to use 2 backslashes as the edit by @hmjd shows or the characters in the directory will be treated as escape characters.

Comment: without error message please dont post code

Comment: I don't get any error. The code compiles fine. Now trying to retrieve what GetLastError() has to say..

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to make sure that the destination folder exists first.  Also you need to make sure that you have write access to the folder.

If MoveFile fails, check the value of GetLastError() immediately afterwards.  It may give useful info.

Comment: I think that you'll also get an error if the file already exists. +1 for mentioning that the OP checks for an error message.

Answer (score 1):

Well got the issue solved.. Got an [error code - 32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which meant that the resource was used by some other process. Actually it was a silly mistake. Forgot to close the file after performing all the operations. Thanks for the help guys, few keywords like GetLastError() helped a lot.. Sorry for being vague about the question..

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) itself says, "If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx)."  Always good to check that first when an API call seems to misbehave.